# Completing MDS manually in R

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, dimensionality-reduction

Given a matrix `A`, I want to complete Multidimensional Scaling by hand, instead of using any given R functions.

As such, I have calculated the centered matrix `B` with the following code:

```
 n<-nrow(A)
 id<-diag(n)
 e<-diag(id)
 H <- id - (1/n)*e %*% etranspose
 B <- (-1/2)* H %*% A %*% H
```

My question is: how can I use my B matrix to complete multidimensional scaling on my A matrix, without the `cmdscale` function or anything along those lines?

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the classic MDS algorithm, it is spelled out very nicely [on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling):

> Classical MDS uses the fact that the coordinate matrix can be derived
>   by eigenvalue decomposition from $B=XX'$. And the matrix $B$ can be
>   computed from proximity matrix $D$ by using double centering.
>
> 1. Set up the squared proximity matrix $D^{(2)}=[d_{ij}^{2}]$
> 2. Apply double centering: $B=-{\frac {1}{2}}JD^{(2)}J$ using the centering matrix $J=I-{\frac {1}{n}}11'$, where $n$ is the number of
>      objects.
> 3. Determine the $m$ largest eigenvalues $\lambda _{1},\lambda _{2},...,\lambda _{m}$ and corresponding eigenvectors $e_{1},e_{2},...,e_{m}$ of $B$ (where $m$ is the number of dimensions
>      desired for the output).
> 4. Now, $X=E_{m}\Lambda _{m}^{1/2}$, where $E_{m}$ is the matrix of $m$ eigenvectors and $\Lambda _{m}$ is the diagonal matrix of $m$
>      eigenvalues of $B$.

I can't really tell what your $A$ matrix is, but if each entry is a measure of the distance from the $i^{th}$ to $j^{th}$ entry, then that would be your *proximity matrix*.

Also, $11'$ is an n-by-n matrix of all 1's. This should be fairly self-explanatory, however most of these terms can be Googled if you're unsure. It really shouldn't be any more than about 10 lines of code.